# Key rotation in paralel asynchronous requests to OpenAI with free tier keys

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, openai-api

I am trying to develop key manager system that will take everytime new keys when current key runs into error or maximum retries per minute which is 3 as I don't have money to pay for bigger tier
so far it is working but sometimes I am running into issue when length of available keys == 0 and I need to initialize new keys and than take new key for request so my asynchronous system is not stopping or interupting myself
please check my key manager

```
db = TinyDB('keys_usage.json', storage=CachingMiddleware(JSONStorage))

class KeyManager:

    def __init__(self, config_path: str = None):
        """
        Initialize the instance.
        """
        if not config_path:
            raise Exception("No OpenAI keys available")

        api_keys, api_base = read_config(config_path)
        openai.api_base = api_base
        self.keys = set(api_keys)  # All keys
        self.using_keys = set()  # Keys that have been used
        self.limited_keys = TTLCache(maxsize=len(self.keys),
                                     ttl=30)  # Keys that have reached the request limit
        self.using_keys_lock = asyncio.Lock()  # Lock for keys and using_keys
        self.limited_keys_lock = asyncio.Lock()  # Separate using_keys_lock for limited_keys



    async def get_new_key(self, key=None) -> str:
        min_ttl = None
        min_key = None

        async with self.using_keys_lock:  # Use async context manager for lock
            logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL} {key} get lock ")
            self.limited_keys.expire()
            unused_keys = self.keys - self.using_keys - set(self.limited_keys.keys())
            logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}unused_keys {len(unused_keys)}")

            if key:
                logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}locked {key}")
                self.limited_keys[key] = time.time()
                self.using_keys.discard(key)

            if unused_keys:
                logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL} limited_keys {len(self.limited_keys.keys())}")
                new_key = random.choice(list(unused_keys))
                self.using_keys.add(new_key)
                return new_key
            else:
                logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}keys {len(self.keys)}")
                logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}using_keys {len(self.using_keys)}")
                logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}limited_keys {len(self.limited_keys.keys())}")

                if len(self.keys) == 0:
                    raise Exception("No OpenAI keys available, all keys have expired")
                else:
                    min_key, min_ttl = self.get_min_ttl_key()
                    if min_ttl:
                        logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}min_ttl {min_ttl}, min_key {min_key}")
                        self.limited_keys.pop(min_key)
                        self.using_keys.add(min_key)

            logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL} {key} leave lock ")

        if min_ttl:
            await asyncio.sleep(min_ttl)
            return min_key
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
            return await self.get_new_key()

    def release_key(self, key):
        """
        Release a key. The key is removed from using_keys.
        """
        self.using_keys.discard(key)

    async def remove_key(self, key):
        """
        Remove a key. The key is removed from keys.
        """
        async with self.using_keys_lock:
            self.keys.discard(key)
            self.using_keys.discard(key)
            self.limited_keys.pop(key, None)
        logging.warning(f"{LOG_LABEL}remove_key {key}")

    def get_key_length(self):
        return len(self.keys)

    def get_min_ttl_key(self):
        if not self.limited_keys:
            return None, None
        now = time.time()
        # Get the remaining TTL for each key and put them in a list
        valid_keys = [(self.limited_keys[key] + self.limited_keys.ttl - now, key)
                      for key in self.limited_keys if self.limited_keys[key] + self.limited_keys.ttl - now > 0]

        min_ttl_key = min(valid_keys)
        return min_ttl_key[1], min_ttl_key[0],

    async def update_key_usage(self, key):
        await asyncio.to_thread(self._sync_update_key_usage, key)

    def _sync_update_key_usage(self, key):
        Key = Query()
        if db.search(Key.id == key):
            db.update(increment('usage_count'), Key.id == key)
        else:
            db.insert({'id': key, 'usage_count': 1, 'last_used': time.time()})

    async def check_key_rotation(self):
        total_keys = len(self.keys)
        used_keys = await asyncio.to_thread(self._sync_check_key_rotation)
        return len(used_keys) >= total_keys * 0.7

    def _sync_check_key_rotation(self):
        return db.search(Query().usage_count >= 3)
```

So I decided in the get_new_key method in the end when I am breaking out from the asyncio_lock

add something like this

```
        else:

            await key_manager_async.initialize_keys()
            keys = list(key_manager_async.available_keys._queue)
            await key_manager_async.save_keys_to_file(keys)
            self.keys = set(keys)

            self.using_keys = set()  # Keys that have been used
            self.limited_keys = TTLCache(maxsize=len(self.keys),
                                         ttl=30)  # Keys that have reached the request limit

            key = await self.get_new_key()


            return key #await self.get_new_key()
```

where I call agaiin my key_manager_async which will generate ney keys and return new key where next step of my code is making request which is happening here

```
async def request_openai_api(openai_model: OpenAIModel, prompt: Prompt, key_manager: KeyManager, max_retries: int) -> Optional[str]:
    key = await key_manager.get_new_key()
    print(f" inreqeust open ai{key}")
    await key_manager.update_key_usage(key)  # Update usage count
    completion = None
    attempts = 0

    while attempts < max_retries:
        try:
            openai_model.set_key(key)
            # Assuming generate is now an async function
            completion = await openai_model.generate(instruction=prompt.instruction, input=prompt.input)
            logging.info(f"{LOG_LABEL}key {key}, request ok")
            key_manager.release_key(key)
            break # break as I am just checking some errors taht might occur
    output = completion['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip()

    return output
```

and returning outpur if all good

so problem is when I reinitialize keys and take new one
requests stops
why this happens
am I using asyncio_lock not correct?

It is not all code yet and if you need more I am more than happy to provide it as I can't understand what is happening when I generate new keys and want to make another request with new key